# Como gerar valores aleatórios para uma distribuição conhecida?

Tags: r, matemática

Tenho conhecimento que, por exemplo `runif(1000,0,3)` gera 1000 valores aleatórios para uma distribuição uniforme para x compreendido entre 0 e 3. Mas como fazer isso para uma função densidade de probabilidade qualquer? Qualquer pista é agradecida!

Comment: Não sou especialista, mas uma busca rápida parece indicar que o problema é mais matemático/estatístico do que de programação. Aparentemente a solução envolve manipular a sua função de forma que ela possa ser alimentada com valores aleatórios (uniformes), e daí gerar os valores com tal distribuição.

Comment: Segundo [este link](http://blog.iseesystems.com/stella-ithink/generating-random-numbers-from-custom-probability-distributions/), você pode obter uma aproximação disso simplesmente ao inverter a função e resolver para valores com distribuição uniforme (se a função for discreta). O ideal seria você postar a função para que possamos tentar resolver o problema.

Comment: Cada distribuição possui uma função específica no R para obtermos amostras. Por exemplo, para obter valores de uma distribuição binomial, a função é `rbinom`, para a distribuição de Poisson, `rpois`. Ambas no pacote **stats** que já vem instalado com o R. No site do projeto (em inglês) há uma [lista](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) com várias distribuições e os pacotes que dão suporte às mesmas. O que está listado em **Base functionality** está incluído em qualquer versão atualizada do R.

Comment: Se a função de densidade é conhecida, vale o comentário do @AiltonAndradedeOliveira, pois há uma função para cada distribuição. Caso seja desconhecida, mas você tenha uma amostra, a questão se complica (eg. qual o domínio da função? Reais? Reais não-negativos? Intervalo definido?).

Answer (score 5):

Toda distribuição estatística pode ser definida por uma função de distribuição acumulada F(x).

Um resultado bastante conhecido afirma que, se você possui uma variável aleatória U com distribuição uniforme no intervalo (0,1). Então [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] segue a distribuição definida por F.

A prova desse resultado é simples:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto se você consegue gerar números aleatórios com a distribuição uniforme e conhece a função de distribuição acumulada, você também consegue gerar números aleatórios de acordo com essa distribuição.

No `R`, isso já está programado para diversas distribuições: ver a [lista](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) que o Ailton postou. Mas, não é muito complicado programar para uma outra distribuição se você conseguir inverter a sua F(x).

---

Se você conhecer apenas a função de distribuição acumulada, você pode escrever como um problema de otimização. Defina a distribuição acumulada ( Aqui é a distribuição acumulada da exponencial):

```
dF <- function(x, lambda = 0.5){
  1 - exp(-lambda*x)
}
```

Sorteie um número aleatório entre 0 e 1 com distribuição uniforme. NO meu caso obtive:

```
n <- 0.917915
```

Em seguida, você tem que encontrar `x` da distribuição `dF` que mais se aproxima de n. Isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
op <- optim(runif(1), function(x){
  abs(dF(x, 0.5) - n)
}, method = "BFGS")
```

Veja que:

```
> op$par
[1] 5
```

E que :

```
> dF(5, 0.5)
[1] 0.917915
```

Esse artigo da wikipedia explica de forma mais completa o que falei aqui:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

---

Esse procedimento pode ser repetido para, a partir de uma amostra aleatória de uma variável aleatória com distribuição uniforme obtermos uma amostra com distribuição acumulada definida no objeto `dF`. No caso usamos a distribuição exponencial:

```
dF <- function(x, lambda = 0.5){
  1 - exp(-lambda*x)
}
amostra <- runif(1000)
```

Para obter a amostra com distribuição exponencial é necessário encontrar o valor da inversa de `dF` para cada número aleatório gerado. Isso pode ser obtido da seguinte maneira:

```
inverter_distribuicao <- function(x){
  m <- nlm(function(y){
      abs(dF(y, 0.5) - x)
    }, p = 1
  )
  return(m$estimate)
}
amostra_exp <- sapply(amostra, inverter_distribuicao)
```

Veja agora o histograma da amostra gerada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]